# EmberJS: Call action from component in named block

Tags: ember.js

I am using named-blocks which I really like but I am unable to call an action from within them. This is an example of my code, the action works perfectly if not in the named-block

**Controller**

```
things = {
  run: false,
  walk: false,
  jog: false,
}

@action
doSomething(thing) {
  this.things[thing] = true;
}
```

**Template**

```
<MyComponent>
<:title>Some cool title...</:title>
<:button><MyButton {{on 'click' (fn this.doSomething 'run')}}/></:button>
</MyComponent>
```

**MyComponent Template**

```
<div>
  {{yield to="title"}}
  {{yield to="button"}}
</div>
```

**MyButton Template**

```
<button type="button>
  Do a thing
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given this component invocation

```
<MyButton {{on 'click' (fn this.doSomething 'run')}}/>
```

the MyButton component must have `...attributes` in order to specify where to place attributes, modifiers, etc -- the "stuff on an element":

```
<button type="button ...attributes>
  Do a thing
</button>
```

Comment: Nice, thats much cleaner than what I was doing. Just a question, is there way to handle multiple splattributes? ie if I want to make `class` go to one child element and the `click handler` to another? We prefer not to pass class in as an arg so I foresee a conflict somewhere down the line.

Comment: (for now) the only way to pull that off would be used yieldable contextual components.  There are some issues open on the RFCs repo, as many people want spreadable all the things -- would be a big ergonomics win.

Here is the RFCs repo: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs

Answer (score -1):

So to solve this I had to modify the templates like so:

```
<MyComponent>
<:title>Some cool title...</:title>
<:button><MyButton @clickAction={{fn this.doSomething 'run'}}/></:button>
</MyComponent>
```

```
<button type="button {{on 'click' @clickAction}}>
  Do a thing
</div>
```

Comment: the issue was that MyButton didn't have ...attributes
so the on click modifier had no where to go